# How to read a line from file given its number?

Tags: java, file, readfile

I have a file that contain 100 line 
each line contain one tag 
I need to obtain the tag value given its rank which is the "id" of TagVertex Class

```
    public abstract class Vertex <T>{

         String vertexId ;// example Tag1

         T vertexValue ;

         public  abstract  T computeVertexValue();
}
```

```
   public class TagVertex extends Vertex<String> {

      @Override
      public String computeVertexValue() {
       // How to get the String from my file?
         return null;
}
```

T try this but it doesnt work

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  File source //

  int i=90;

  int j=0;

  String s = null;

  try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        if (j==i) s= scanner.nextLine();

         else j++;
    }


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(s);
  }}
```

Comment: So in cleartext, you want to read the 100th line of a file?

Comment: What do you mean by rank ? The line number ?

Comment: @Philipp i want to read the ith line of file

Comment: @Nicolas yes the line number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is a way to skip characters with BufferedReader, I don't think there's is a built-in way to skip whole lines.

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MyFile.txt"));

for(int i = 1; i < myVertex.vertexId; i++){
    bf.readLine();
}

String n = bf.readLine();
if(n != null){
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

I think there may be a better idea though.

Answer (score 0):

This is command u can use to read from file:

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));
```

This will read the file to the buffer.
Now, for reading each line u should use a while loop and read each line into string.
Like:

```
String str;
while((str = bf.readLine()) != null){
//handle each line untill the end of file which will be null and quit the loop
}
```